# How to make a comment in issue to the top?

Tags: github

There are many comments in an issue, and I think one of them is important, so I want to set this comment  to the top of the issue.

Is this possible? How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Comments are listed in the order that they were made, and this order cannot be adjusted.

You can, however, *link* to a comment by clicking the three dots on the right of it, then clicking `Copy link`. Pasting this link into the navbar will take you straight to the individual comment if it is needed as a reference at a later date.

This will work for comments on both issues and pull requests.

[image: Comment]